# What is the most idiomatic style to force a computation using Sequences in f#?

Tags: arrays, f#, sequences, deferred

I have a side-effective operation

```
     securities |> Seq.map (fun x -> request.Append("securities",x))
```

What is the most idiomatic way to have the code perform ?

I wrote a Seq.Doit, but it itches

```
  module Seq =
     let Doit sa = sa |> Seq.toArray |> ignore
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deferred sequences are used when you create sequences using `Seq.delay` or sequence expression seq{}. Any function on sequence returning any datatype other than `seq` can force computation.

Alternatively, you can use `for` loop instead of `Seq.iter`:

```
for s in securities do
   request.Append("securities", s)
```

If you want to hide side effects and return `request` for later use, `Seq.fold` is a good choice:

```
securities |> Seq.fold (fun acc x -> acc.Append("securities", x); acc) request
```

Answer (score 6):

I think [**`Seq.iter`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340396.aspx) is appropriate in this case. From the MSDN reference page:

> ```
> Seq.iter : ('T -> unit) -> seq<'T> -> unit
> ```
>
> *Applies the given function to each element of the collection.*

So, supposing that `request.Append` does not return anything, your code becomes:

```ml
securities |> Seq.iter (fun x -> request.Append("securities", x))
```

Comment: very well observed. map + doit = iter

Comment: note that with `seq` the computation is acutally delayed until after the `seq` is converted to a list / array or something which removes it from the `seq` type